Filament login not working in staging/production
Filament login not working in staging/production.
I'm setting up my site on a Linux staging server, but filament is not working as expected. Whenever I try to login, not only the password is not hashed (it shows as plain text) but I get this error

The POST method is not supported for route admin/login. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

I really don't know what to do,
I read all the articles I've found and threads too- my network tab is not showing missing assets, like livewire, which works on other parts of the website, (but not hashed password makes me think otherwise); the only error showing up in devTools is

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on the in source tab

no idea why. Please help- Thanks in advance.

unexpected token '<' prbably means there is an error page trying to be loaded in the javascript or in the page itself
